# Mouse position relative to origin

Tags: charts, javafx-2

How do I calculate the position of the mouse relative to the origin of a line chart?

The code below gets the x-position of the mouse cursor relative to the layout origin of the chart. I'd like to know the mouse position relative to the Cartesian origin instead.

```
public class Chart extends Application {

    private NumberAxis xAxis;
    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    private LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart;
    private Label cursorPosition;
    private Label xAxisPosition;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();

        xAxis = new NumberAxis("Date", 0.f, 100.f, 10.f);
        yAxis = new NumberAxis("Value", 0.f, 100.f, 10.f);
        lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

    Series series = new Series();
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 100; ii++) {
        series.getData().add(new Data(ii, Math.random()*20.));
    }
    lineChart.getData().add(series);

    lineChart.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            lineChart.setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
            cursorPosition.setText(String.valueOf(event.getX()));
        }
    });

    lineChart.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            lineChart.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        }
    });

    cursorPosition = new Label();
    root.getChildren().addAll(lineChart, cursorPosition,);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the chart's axes to convert between display coordinates and cartesian (value) coordinates. `xAxis.getDisplayPosition(0)` would, for instance, give you the x coordinate for the value 0. You can also use this to convert the current mouse position into 'values'.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to use  xAxis.getDisplayPosition to determine the pixel position of a data point relative to the origin. Do you know how to get the position of the origin itself?